# What mistake have i made in my code? Its running but not providing the answer that it should for the input i have shown

Tags: python

Here is the question:

You have graduated from MIT and now have a great job! You move to the San Francisco Bay Area and
decide that you want to start saving to buy a house.  As housing prices are very high in the Bay Area,
you realize you are going to have to save for several years before you can afford to make the down
payment on a house. In Part A, we are going to determine how long it will take you to save enough
money to make the payment given the following assumptions:

1. Call the cost of your dream home 'i'.
2. Call the amount that you have saved thus far 'current'. You start with a current
   savings of $0.
3. Assume that you invest your current savings wisely, with an annual return of r (in other words,
   at the end of each month, you receive an additional 'current*r/12' funds to put into
   your savings – the 12 is because r is an annual rate). Assume that your investments earn a
   return of r = 0.04 (4%).
4. Assume your annual salary is i.
5. Assume you are going to dedicate a certain amount of your salary each month to saving for
   the down payment. Call that 'p'. This variable should be in decimal form (i.e. 0.1
   for 10%).
6. At the end of each month, your savings will be increased by the return on your investment,
   plus a percentage of your monthly salary (annual salary / 12).
   Write a program to calculate how many months it will take you to save up enough money for a down
   payment. You will want your main variables to be floats, so you should cast user inputs to floats.
   Your program should ask the user to enter the following variables:
7. The starting annual salary (i)
8. The portion of salary to be saved (p)
9. The cost of your dream home (c)

Here is my code:

```
i=int(input("Enter your annual salary:"))
p=float(input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:"))
c=float(input("Enter the cost of your dream home:"))
r=0
current=float(i*p*r/12)
for r in range(9999999):
    if current<c:
        current=current*(0.04)/12
    else:
        break
print("Number of months ="+ str( int(r)))
```

The correct ouput required for below input was:

```
Enter your annual salary: 120000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .10
Enter the cost of your dream home: 1000000
Number of months: 1000
```

but the output i am getting is:

```
Enter your annual salary:120000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:.10
Enter the cost of your dream home:1000000
Number of months =9999998
```

can anyone please show why i am wrong?

PS:: extremely sorry earlier i had uploaded a slightly different Question;
i have now provided the relevant Question.

Comment: [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: why are you using `for i in range(999999999)`?

Comment: @Ironkey since the answer will be well short of 999999999, i could not think of any other way to run the for loop

Comment: look into a `while True` loop

Comment: I don't see why 1,000 months is the correct output for $120,000 / 10% / $1,000,000 as input arguments. That's how long it would take if you were trying to save up $1,000,000 saving $1,000 per month without accruing any interest whatsoever on the amount you'd saved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 current=current*(0.04)/12
```

In this line, you do not accumulate, but you simply overwrite the value of current.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write out your solution on paper and ask yourself if it makes sense.

```
for r in range(9999999):
    if current<c:
        current=current*(0.04)/12
    else:
        break
print("Number of months ="+ str( int(r)))
```

What I'm noticing is that `current` will always be 0 no matter what because `0 < 1000000` will always be true if `current` isn't changing.

`current=current*(0.04)/12` is essentially `0=0*(0.04)/12`, see how that will always be 0?

When `r` goes through all "9999999" in the range, `r` will stop right before that, break, and return to you what you're noticing `Number of months =9999998`.

The code itself is running normally, but I would recheck the logic.